# use of resumable option in upload request for google drive

Tags: curl, google-drive-api

I want to upload a file independently of the size. I use the "resumable" option. The code below works with a text file but when I use a pdf file, or an other extension (jpg, 7z), I  always have the 503 error. Moreover, if I want to send by chunk, I receive the code 308.
Furthermore, is it possible to add user metadata as "key=value".

```
// Get Buffer
pInputName = fopen (FILE_PATH,"rb");
if (pInputName==NULL) {
    perror ("Error opening file");
    return (-1);
}
else
{
    resultat = fseek(pInputName, 0, SEEK_END);
    filesize= (size_t) ftell(pInputName);
    rewind(pInputName);
    buffer = (char *) calloc(filesize+1, sizeof(char));
    resultat = fread (buffer,sizeof(char),filesize,pInputName);
    fclose (pInputName);
}


// GET LOCATION
sprintf_s(tmp, 100, "Authorization: Bearer %s",auth);
headerList = curl_slist_append(headerList, tmp);

curl_easy_reset(curl);
curl_easy_setopt( curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=resumable") ;
curl_easy_setopt( curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1 ) ;
curl_easy_setopt( curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, titre ) ;
curl_easy_setopt( curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1 ) ;

sprintf_s(tmp,100,"Content-Length: %d",size_titre);
headerList = curl_slist_append(headerList, tmp);
headerList = curl_slist_append(headerList, "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
headerList = curl_slist_append(headerList, "X-Upload-Content-Type: text/plain");
sprintf_s(tmp,100,"X-Upload-Content-Length: %d",filesize);
headerList = curl_slist_append(headerList, tmp);
curl_easy_setopt( curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,  headerList) ;

curl_easy_setopt( curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_easy_setopt( curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &writeMemory);
curl_easy_setopt( curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteMemoryCallback);
curl_easy_setopt( curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);
curl_easy_setopt( curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0L);

        curl_easy_perform(curl);

value = getValue(&writeMemory, "Location: ", ',');

// PUT Request
curl_slist_free_all(headerList);
headerList = NULL;
curl_easy_reset(curl);
curl_easy_setopt( curl, CURLOPT_URL, value) ;
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
curl_easy_setopt( curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, buffer ) ;
curl_easy_setopt( curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, strlen(buffer) ) ;

sprintf_s(tmp, 100, "Authorization: Bearer %s",auth);
headerList = curl_slist_append(headerList, tmp);
sprintf_s(tmp,100,"Content-Length: %d",filesize);
headerList = curl_slist_append(headerList, tmp);
headerList = curl_slist_append(headerList, "Content-Type: application/pdf");
sprintf_s(tmp, 100, "Content-Range: bytes */%d", filesize);
headerList = curl_slist_append(headerList, tmp);

curl_easy_setopt( curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_easy_setopt( curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &writeMemoryPut);
curl_easy_setopt( curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteMemoryCallback);
curl_easy_setopt( curl, CURLOPT_WRITEHEADER, &writeMemory);
curl_easy_setopt( curl, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, WriteMemoryCallback);
curl_easy_setopt( curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);
curl_easy_setopt( curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0L);

curl_easy_perform(curl);
```

Comment: I found the problem for pdf file. In fact, I changed strlen(buffer) by filesize

Comment: For information, it works if you add "curl_easy_setopt( curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,  headerList) ;" so for the last chunk, I receive 200 OK